ECC Point-Scalar multiplication
I implemented my own Double-and-add method to make a public key from a private key using SECP256K1's parameters, this is how my code looks so far
Point* KeyGenerator::ECMul(uint512_t privKey, Point* point)
{
    if (privKey == 0 || privKey > n)
    {
        throw new std::exception("Invalid private key!\n");
    }
        
    Point* Q = new Point(0, 0); //infinity point
    Point* pnt = new Point(point->_x, point->_y);
    for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++)
    {
        if (privKey % 2) { //if first bit is set
            Q = ECAdd(Q, pnt);
        }

        pnt = ECDouble(pnt);
        privKey /= 2;
    }

    return Q;
}

Also adding the implementation of my ECAdd and ECDouble functions below
Point* KeyGenerator::ECDouble(Point* pnt) 
{
    if (pnt->is_infinity()) return new Point(0, 0); // Point at infinity

    uint512_t deltaY = (2 * pnt->_y);
    uint512_t deltaX = (3 * pnt->_x * pnt->_x + ACurve);
    uint512_t lambda = (deltaX * mod_inverse(deltaY, PCurve)) % PCurve;

    uint512_t x3 = (lambda * lambda - 2 * pnt->_x) % PCurve;
    uint512_t y3 = (lambda * (pnt->_x - x3) - pnt->_y) % PCurve;

    return new Point(x3, y3);
}

Point* KeyGenerator::ECAdd(Point* pnt1, Point* pnt2) 
{
    if (pnt1->is_infinity()) return pnt2;
    if (pnt2->is_infinity()) return pnt1;
    if (pnt1->_x == pnt2->_x && pnt1->_y == pnt2->_y) return ECDouble(pnt1);
    if (pnt1->_x == pnt2->_x && pnt1->_y != pnt2->_y) return new Point(0, 0); // Point at infinity

    uint512_t deltaY = (pnt2->_y - pnt1->_y);
    uint512_t deltaX = (pnt2->_x - pnt1->_x);

    uint512_t lambda = (deltaY * mod_inverse(deltaX, PCurve)) % PCurve;

    uint512_t x3 = (lambda * lambda - pnt1->_x - pnt2->_x) % PCurve;
    uint512_t y3 = (lambda * (pnt1->_x - x3) - pnt1->_y) % PCurve;

    return new Point(x3, y3);
}

using Boost's uint512_t to handle numbers that may overflow

So for some reason, whenever i run this function, i get wrong answers, this is either my multiplication Double-and-add method being wrong, or the double function being incorrect, for some reason i just cannot find any other implementation i can compare with

I see at least one problem: there can be an overflow in the second and third of these three expressions:
uint512_t deltaY = (2 * pnt->_y);
uint512_t deltaX = (3 * pnt->_x * pnt->_x + ACurve);
uint512_t lambda = (deltaX * mod_inverse(deltaY, PCurve)) % PCurve;

Problem in the second expression is: if $x$ is a little below $2^{256}$ as it can be, then $3x^2$ is 514 bit. And even if $x$ is small enough that there is no overflow there, most likely there is overflow in the next multiplication, which absent overflow would produce an about 768-bit number.
I think both problems can be fixed by replacing these three expressions with
uint512_t lambda = ((3 * (pnt->_x * pnt->_x % PCurve) + ACurve) % PCurve)
                   * mod_inverse(2 * pnt->_y, PCurve) % PCurve;


I'm afraid there are other issues with the - operator for uint512_t operands. It is defined such that it's a non-negative integer equal to the difference modulo $2^{512}$, in the sense modulo has in mathematics(1). Thus e.g. deltaX = (pnt2->_x - pnt1->_x); can underflow and give a result that's incorrect modulo PCurve, a classical programming problem. One (inefficient) way to fix it is using that if a, b and p are uint512_t and p is in $[1,2^{511}]$, then the mathematical expression $(\mathtt a-\mathtt b)\bmod\mathtt p$ can be computed as (a % p + p - b % p ) % p.
Note: n is an invalid private key, but is accepted by ECMul.
Note: in ECMul, for (int i = 0; i < 512; i++) makes way more loops than required. An optimization is to replace it with while (privKey!=0).
Again: Boost's uint512_t is far from ideal for cryptographic use. It gives neither side channel resistance, nor good speed. And it's not even easy to use for modular arithmetic: because it's unsigned, - underflows (see above). And if we switch to a signed type in boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp, I think there is the issue that the % operator can return negative values even if the modulus is strictly positive.

(1) Quoting the nice manual

Unsigned types support subtraction - the result is "as if" a 2's complement operation had been performed…


Thank you for the answer, i've taken this into consideration and realized that using an unsigned int was infact not correct behavior, before you posted this comment i actually tried using an int512_t, yet i still got negative values, that resulted in negative modular arithmatics answers, (Which you as well predicted), cpp_int makes more sense now, and I will try to make something to challenge the negative value with the % operator. I really appreciate it

@DayDrunk: int512_tshould work for you, if instead of the built-in % operator you use int512_t modint512(int512_t a, int512_t m) { a<0 ? -((-a)%m):a%m; } and restrict to strictly positive modulus m. You still need to avoid the overflows in the beginning of my answer.

I see, Thank you very much!

Okay so after further research, i DEFINITELY have an issue with my ECDouble function, It shouldn't overflow since im using arbitrary sized cpp_int, so im just left here confused. This is my implementation.
    if (pnt->is_infinity()) return new Point(0, 0); // Point at infinity
    cpp_int lambda = mod((3 * pnt->_x * pnt->_x + ACurve)
        * mod_inverse(2 * pnt->_y, PCurve), PCurve);
    cpp_int x3 = mod((lambda * lambda * -2 * pnt->_x), PCurve);
    cpp_int y3 = mod((lambda * (pnt->_x - x3) - pnt->_y), PCurve);
    return new Point(x3, y3);
}```

@DayDrunk: lambda * (pnt->_x - x3) - pnt->_y will often get negative, and I don't know if your modhandles that the way the mathematical $\bmod$ does. Which is, always return a result in $[0,\text{PCurve})$. lambda * lambda * -2 * pnt->_x can also (rarely) be negative.

I account for negative values, my mod function is basically the same as your idea above.

@DayDrunk: You use the standard formulas. I can't tell if you use the right PCurve and ACurve, but notice that ACurve is zero for secp256k1. Also I can't check your test that ECDoubledoes not work.

God damn it I figured it out.. turns out I was missing a modulo call in my ECAdd function, as well as not really looking into the mod implementation and returning (-a)%m instead of the CORRECT value of (a % m + m) % m. Thank you so much for the support over these couple of days, I really appreciate it.

(a % m + m) % m is correct, but a<0 ? -((-a)%m) : a%m; tends to be faster in Boost. @DayDrunk
